# Android implement CoordinatorLayout and Framelayout

Tags: android

I am using below code in my app main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.keyhan_soft.gps.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you see i included Fragment layout in `<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>` line, but it is static way, how can i replace this static way with dynamic `FrameLayout` solution?
I want to add fragments programmatically

Comment: Yes, you can add dynamically to the framelayout, what is the problem?

Comment: This will be ok if i replace include layout with frame layout?

Answer (score 1):

You may try following way to do `FragmentTransaction` which replace your `Fragment` in `content_main` layout.Below method use for `FragmentTransaction`.

**Method:**

```
public void pushFragments(Fragment fragment, boolean shouldAdd, String tag) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();//Use this line for FragmentManager , if you are in Activity
    //FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();//Use this line for FragmentManager , if you are in Fragment
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

    //manager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);//Uncomment this line if you don't want to maintain Fragment Backsack
    ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment, tag);
    if (shouldAdd) {
        ft.addToBackStack(tag); //add fragment in backstack
    }
    ft.commit();
}
```

I am giving example for how to do `FragmentTransaction`.

**YourFragment.java**

```
public class YourFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private View rootView;

    public YourFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_your_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
pushFragments(new YourFragment(), 
 true, // true --> add Fragment in backstack else false
"YourFragment"); // Fragment tag which help to find your fragment
```

I hope its help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give Framelayout as a container where you can give your fragment dynamically.

Layoutfile 
*collapse_screen_test.xml*

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frgmentcontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"></FrameLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:fabSize="normal" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In Activity last i am replacing fragment dynamically

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frgmentcontainer, new HomeScreen(), "Home").commit();
```

**CollpaseScreen**

```
public class CollpaseScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.collapse_screen_test);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    replace(new HomeScreen(), false, "Home");

}

public void replace(Fragment fragment, boolean addtostack, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frgmentcontainer, fragment, tag);
    if (addtostack)
        ft.addToBackStack(tag);
    ft.commit();
}
```

}

*HomeScreen Fragment*

```
public class HomeScreen extends Fragment{
    public static final String TAG = "Home";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_screen, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

***home_screen*** fragment layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/htmltext"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```