# Unable to start fragment from onListItemClick

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm trying to start a fragment from OnItemClickListener event of list view but its not showing anything. to check if the OnItemClickListener is functional or not, I've included a Toast to show some text and its working fine. 
Here is my code

Here is the code for ItemClickListener of main activity

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

            Fragment fragment = new Friendtilefragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.friendtilefragment, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An item of the ListView is clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Code for the Friendtilefragment

```
package com.example.xxxxxxxx.socialoid;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Friendtilefragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.friendtilefragment_layout, container, false);
}
}
```

mainactivity_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:divider="@color/list_divider"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/friendtilefragment"
    android:name="com.example.xxxxxxxx.socialoid.Friendtilefragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

friendtilefragment_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is textview"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the error you getting

Comment: change it   Friendtilefragment fragment = new Friendtilefragment();

Comment: Nothing . no errors and its really frustrating.

Comment: @NigamPatro,It's not mandatory to take FrameLayout to adding fragment.

Comment: @deejay,Might be your ListView take whole screen how many items in ListView ?

Comment: @NigamPatro I've read other posts and some have used framelayout others are using Fragment.. so i think its not the issue.And if there was a problem with it, it must have shown some errors.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I'm loading listview with json data and I've got only 2 items in my list.
ListView height is set to WrapContent..

Comment: @deejay,Try to set SwipeRefreshLayout height as match_parent instead of wrap_content.

Comment: still same.. no errors in log either.

Comment: @deejay move `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An item of the ListView is clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` to `Friendtilefragment`, see whether the Toast can get displayed in your fragment or not

Comment: Toast is working.. i can see it.

Comment: Move the Toast to Friendtilefragment

Comment: unreachable statement while using Toast in fragment..I've tried replacing getApplicationContext with getActivity() but unreachable.

Comment: @deejay check this answer to  know how change fragment  http://stackoverflow.com/a/34357147/1140237  specifilcally `CollpaseScreen` activity

Comment: Thanks @user1140237.. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a  `FrameLayout` in your MainActivity and move `android:id="@+id/friendtilefragment"` to `FrameLayout`.

**Example in your mian_activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/friendtilefragment">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

.....
```

Between, change  `Fragment fragment = new Friendtilefragment();` to `Friendtilefragment fragment = new Friendtilefragment();`

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080569/why-fragment-layout-cannot-be-displayed)

Comment: I'm trying this code.. and do i need to remove the fragment tag completely?

Comment: Ya, you can remove it and see whether it works or not

Comment: I mean the problem we discussed in chat, not here

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Fragment fragment = new Friendtilefragment();
```

with this

```
Friendtilefragment fragment = new Friendtilefragment();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this .. 
replace the code with your  `mainactivity_layout.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/friendtilefragment"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:divider="@color/list_divider"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />    
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I Hope this works..